# Create table name in Hive using variable subsitution

Tags: hive

I'd like to create a table name in Hive using variable substitution.
E.g.

```
SET market = "AUS";
create table ${hiveconf:market_cd}_active as ... ;
```

But it fails. Any idea how it can be achieved?

Comment: *"But it fails.*" is no appropriate error description. Please provide the error message to give us more insight and increase the chance of getting a qualified answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should use backtrics (``) for name for that, like:

```sql
SET market=AUS;

CREATE TABLE `${hiveconf:market}_active` AS SELECT 1;

DESCRIBE `${hiveconf:market}_active`;
```

Example run script.sql from beeline:

```
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/ -n hadoop -f script.sql
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
...
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/> SET market=AUS;
No rows affected (0.057 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/> CREATE TABLE `${hiveconf:market}_active` AS SELECT 1;
...
INFO  : Dag name: CREATE TABLE `AUS_active` AS SELECT 1(Stage-1)
...
INFO  : OK
No rows affected (12.402 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/> DESCRIBE `${hiveconf:market}_active`;
...
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20190801194250_1a57e6ec-25e7-474d-b31d-24026f171089): DESCRIBE `AUS_active`
...
INFO  : OK
+-----------+------------+----------+
| col_name  | data_type  | comment  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| _c0       | int        |          |
+-----------+------------+----------+
1 row selected (0.132 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/> Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
```

Answer (score 2):

Markovitz's criticisms are correct, but do not produce a correct solution.  In summary, you can use variable substitution for things like string comparisons, but NOT for things like naming variables and tables.  If you know much about language compilers and parsers, you get a sense of why this would be true.   You could construct such behavior in a language like Java, but SQL is just too crude.

Running that code produces an error, "cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hiveconf' in table name".(I am running Hortonworks, Hive 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37).

I spent a couple hours Googling and experimenting with different combinations of punctuation, different tools ranging from command line, Ambari, and DB Visualizer, etc., and I never found any way to construct a table name or a field name with a variable value.  I think you're stuck with using variables in places where you need a string literal, like comparisons, but you cannot use them in place of reserved words or existing data structures, if that makes sense.  By example:

--works

drop table if exists user_rgksp0.foo;

-- Does NOT work:

set MY_FILE_NAME=user_rgksp0.foo; 
--drop table if exists ${hiveconf:MY_FILE_NAME};

-- Works

set REPORT_YEAR=2018;

select count(1) as stationary_event_count, day, zip_code, route_id from aaetl_dms_pub.dms_stationary_events_pub

where part_year = '${hiveconf:REPORT_YEAR}'

-- Does NOT Work:

set MY_VAR_NAME='zip_code'

select count(1) as stationary_event_count, day, '${hiveconf:MY_VAR_NAME}', route_id from aaetl_dms_pub.dms_stationary_events_pub

where part_year = 2018

Answer (score 1):

1. The qualifies should be removed
2. You're using the wrong variable name

---

```
SET market=AUS; create table ${hiveconf:market}_active as select 1;
```